# Showing a sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $f(x)$ be a function which is diﬀerentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and for which $a = \sup\{|f
′(x)| : x ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$ is less than 1. Let $x_{0}$ be any ﬁxed real number.

(a) Show that the sequence ${x_{i}}$ deﬁned by $x_{i+1} = f(x_{i})$ for $i ≥ 0$
is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent.

(b) Show that $f(x)$ has a fixed point.

I really wish I had an attempt to show you guys, but I don't lol. I'm very lost with this question.

I know that to be Cauchy the terms in a sequence have to be arbitrarily close together. How can I show this given the above information?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. For any two different points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
   $$\big|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\big|< 1,$$
   or $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|.$ Else, you could get a contradiction using mean value theorem that there exists point $c$ in the interval say $(x,y)$ such that $1 > |f'(c)| = \big|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\big| \geq 1$.
2. And since $a = \sup\{|f'(x)|\} < 1$, the above statement can be strengthened to 
   $$\big|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\big|\leq a,$$
   or
   $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq a|x-y|.$$
3. $|f(f(x)) - f(f(y))| \leq a|f(x) - f(y)| \leq a^2|x-y|.$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How did you arrive at 2? And from 3, how can we conclude the Cauchy property?

Comment: @RubberDucky My answer below gives all the details required. This question is simply a special case of the Banach Fixed Point theorem. I am skeptical about this answer, particularly the $(1-a)$ terms that appear everywhere.

Comment: @Frank Alright, I will give yours another look over. I followed up on this because it seemed simpler at first.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write $a$, instead of $(1-a)$, was too tired yesterday :(

Comment: Still, your answer only deals with applying the MVT to iterations of $ f $ which isn't especially helpful.

Comment: @Frank My hint was meant for one to see that f is a contraction mapping on the complete metric space R. Since the poster didn't know how to approach this problem, I was trying to point to the right starting direction. And if he is familiar with the Banach fixed-point theorem, the problem would be finished.

Comment: @Xiao No it wouldn't be over as you apply the MVT in a way that isn't that illuminating in this context.

Comment: @Frank How so? If we know $f$ is a contraction mapping on the complete metric space R, then there exists a fixed point $x^*$ which can be approximated by a sequence starting with any arbitrary $x_0$ and $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Note that by induction plus the Mean Value Theorem

$$|x_{k+1} - x_k| \leq a^{k}|x_1-x_0|$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

(**More Detail**: Key to inductive step: $|x_{k+2} - x_{k+1}| = |f(x_{k+1}) - f(x_k)| \leq a|x_{k+1} - x_k|$, by the MVT.)

Hence for any $m>n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ we have that

$$|x_m - x_n| \leq |x_m- x_{m-1}| + \cdots + |x_{n+1}-x_n| $$

$$ \leq a^{m-1}|x_{1} - x_{0}| + \cdots +a^n|x_1-x_0|$$

$$ = a^n|x_1-x_0|\sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1}a^k$$

$$\leq a^n|x_1-x_0|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k $$

$$ = a^n|x_1-x_0| \dfrac{a}{1-a},$$

from which the Cauchy property follows easily (because $a^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, independently of $m$; and the remaining terms in the final product are constant).

(b) We now know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$ exists and we denote this limit by $x$. Taking limits in the equation $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and using the continuity of $f$ shows that $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks a bunch for the help!